# Простой линейный алгоритм на си, почему он не работает? :(

Tags: c

У меня несколько глупый вопрос, мне нужно написать простую программу на си, линейный алгоритм который считал бы функцию, но оно не работает! Почему? :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float x,y,z,a,b,p;
    printf("x,a,b = \n");
    scanf("%f",&x);
    scanf("%f",&a);
    scanf("%f",&b);
    y = (sin(x)+1.5)/2;
    p = pow(a,1.0/4.0);
    z = (pow(y,3)+p+3.3)/(b+p+3.3);
    printf("%f,%f", &y,&z);

    return 0;
}
```

Задание:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где корень из p+3.3?

Comment: Приведите задание в текстовом виде

Answer (score 3):

Ты выводишь адреса переменных, а не сами переменные.

Answer (score 0):

```
p = sqrt(sqrt(a) + 3.3);
z = (pow(y, 3) + p) / (b + p);

printf("%f,%f", y, z);
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что внешний корень распространяется на *(корень из a) + 3.3*, а не только на корень из *a*... Посмотрите внимательно, докуда тянется горизонтальная черта радикала.

Answer (score -1):

для извлечения корня квадратного есть функция sqrt(), если ты вводишь угол в градусах, то аргумент синуса нужно умножить на ПИ, т.к. он в радианах.

```
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float x,y,z,a,b,p;
    printf("x,a,b = \n");
    scanf("%f",&x);
    scanf("%f",&a);
    scanf("%f",&b);
    y = (sin(x*PI)+1.5)*0.5;
    z = (pow(y,3)+sqrt(sqrt(a)+3.3)/(b+sqrt(sqrt(a)+3.3));
    printf("%f,%f", &y,&z);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "если ... угол в градусах, то аргумент синуса нужно умножить на ПИ" - и всё?

Comment: Во-первых угол нужно еще и поделить на `180`, а во-вторых там не написано, в радианах угол или в градусах...

Comment: Там четко написано - значение `x` и формула - `sin(x)`, тут и обсуждать нечего...